# Regarding enumeration of various kinds of relations on a set

Tags: relations

The Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS, popularly known as Sloane, databases more than $320000$ integer sequences. Among these are the sequences counting transitive relations $t(n)$ and partial orders $p(n)$ on a set with $n$ elements. Interestingly, a general formula for $t(n)$ is unknown and so is the case with $p(n)$. However, OEIS enlists both $t(n)$ and $p(n)$ for $n, 0\leq n\leq 18$.

Is there a relation between $t(n)$ and $p(n)$?

Comment: If you're talking about A001035 and A006905 then a relationship between them is given on their OEIS page. $t(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n p(k+1)\sum_{s=0}^k  \binom{n}{ s}S(n-s, k-s)$ where $S(n,k)$ is the Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $t(n)$ is [OEIS sequence A006905](https://oeis.org/A006905) "Number of transitive relations on n labeled nodes".

$p(n)$ is [OEIS sequence A001035](https://oeis.org/A001035) "Number of partially ordered sets with n labeled elements.".

For the relation between them see [log plot A001035 vs. A006905](https://oeis.org/plot2a?name1=A001035&name2=A006905&tform1=log+base+10&tform2=log+base+10&shift=0&radiop1=xy&drawpoints=true)

The OEIS entry for A006905 states:

> E.g.f.: A(x + exp(x) - 1) where A(x) is the e.g.f. for A001035.

This is equivalent to the formula in the
PARI and Mathematica code given in the entry
$$ t(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n p(k)T(n,k)\;\; \text{ where }\;\; 
T(n,k) :=\sum_{j=0}^k  \binom{n}{j}S(n-j, k-j) $$
where $S(n,k)$ is the Stirling numbers of the second kind.
For example,
$$ t(0) = p(0) = 1,\\
t(1) = 2p(1) = 2,\\
t(2) = p(1)+4p(2) = 13,\\
t(3) = p(1)+6p(2)+8p(3) = 171. $$
Note that $\,T(n,k)\,$ is
[OEIS sequence A340264](https://oeis.org/A340264).